# How can write a oracle query as generic alternative way of union

Tags: java, performance, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table `attach` with huge data sets, it is a temp table and created by sql:

```
    id   number   name
    1      X1     name1
    2      X2     name2
    3      X3     name3
    4      X4     name4
```

table `attachment_map`

```
    id    item    attach_id  file_id  versionid
    1      X1       1          100         0
    2      X2       0           0          1
```

table `version`

```
   id    attach_id   
    1      2
```

I want to have query to get:

```
    id   number   name    item
    1      X1     name1    X1
    2      X2     name2    X2
    3      X3     name3
    4      X4     name4
```

As you can see, the return rows added new column which actually got from table `attachment_map`, there have three impossibles:

1).`attach` don't have item.

2).Have item, by connecting to column `attach_id` of `attachment_map`.

2).Have item, by connecting to column `attach_id` of `version`.

I wrote a query but having poor performance, executed it slowly and it seems because of union. can everybody tell another way or how I can improvee it? thanks

```
 WITH tb AS
(SELECT t.*,
 i.item
 FROM attach t,
  attachment_map am,
  version v
 WHERE (am.attach_id = t.attachid
OR (am.file_id      = 0
AND am.version_id   = v.id))
)
SELECT * FROM tb
UNION
SELECT tb.*, NULL FROM tb, attach WHERE tp.id NOT IN (attach.id);
```

Comment: what does the alias "i" refer to (i.item)?

Comment: not a complete left join, because as I mentioned there have three impossibles to get item value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s to link the three tables, and then `CASE` the `item` fields in the order of priority (first inspect attach, then attachment_map, then version).

```
SELECT t.*
, case when t.attach_id is null then
    case when am.attach_id is null then
        v.item
    else
        am_attach.item
    end
else
    t.item
end as chosen_item

FROM attach t
left outer join attachment_map am on am.attach_id = t.attachid
left outer join version v on am.version_id   = v.id
```

Comment: Rather than a case expression, could you use coalesce directly on the various items?

Comment: @Tom: yes, that should work just as well (and I *think* COALESCE is SQL Standard, in which case it's a little better)

Comment: I believe both `coalesce` and `case` are in the standard. Which is not to say that the implementations available in databases comply with the standard!